# Python Selenium user data not loading in headless mode

Tags: python, selenium

When I create a profile and log into the account, the next time I create a driver using the same profile all accounts are stored. However, when I switch to headless, the profile does not seem to be recognized.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=" + running_loc + "\\profiles\\" + profile)  # Path to your chrome profile
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")

if 'visual' not in args:
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--window-size=2560,1440")

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME
caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(cache_valid_range=7).install(), desired_capabilities=caps,
                          options=options)
```

So in the above code, when running non-headless, I face no issues with logins, but in headless everything requires a login once again.